# How to insert XML elements into the browser DOM

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm using jQuery Ajax to retrieve an XML document from the server which I then want to transform into HTML and inject into the browser DOM. I'm retrieving it using dataType:'xml' so it's wrapped as an XML document rather than HTML. This allows me to do the manipulation I want to do before insertion.

However, I can't find a way to insert the manipulated xml into the DOM:

```
$('#myContainer').append(myXML)
```

causes a security violation in IE and has no effect in Firefox, while

```
$('#myContainer').append(myXML[0].xml)
```

works in IE but not Firefox (the xml property appears to be non-standard)

`myXML.text()` returns only the text nodes from the XML, and not the markup, while `myXML.html()` returns null.

I've also tried retrieving it as text, which allows me to create a "standard" jQuery object which inserts just fine. However, I have the following sort of thing going on:

```
<div><input type='checkbox'><otherElement/></input></div>
```

and want to modify the `input` element based on the contents of `otherElement`. If I recover the original xml as text, jQuery reduces it to

```
<div><input type='checkbox'><otherElement/></div>
```

so that the parent element of `otherElement` is the `div` and not the `input`, making manipulation of the input element unreliable. The same occurs if I retrieve it as html.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to load it using 'dataType':'text' and then use $parseXML to create the jQuery object. This preserves the markup, and nodes from the resulting object can be inserted into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I would retrive it as html, manipulate it, and then attach it to the DOM:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({"url":"/ajax.whatever",
        "dataType":"html",
        "success":function(data) {
           var html = $(data);
           // modify html as a jquery object
           // ...
           $("#myContainer").append(html);
        }
}    );
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, retrieving it as html has the same problem as retrieving it as text - the content of the document is changed to that children of input elements are effectively re-parented.